# Where are Microsoft Teams background images located on a Windows 10 computer

Tags: microsoft-teams

Where are the image files used for Microsoft Teams backgrounds stroed on a Windows 10 computer?  I've looked through `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams` but didn't see any in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to background images that you yourself added, they are in:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads
```

Thanks for the variable @dtw ..

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  Now I've added an image to that folder but it isn't appearing in Background Settings. Is there another step?  And does it matter that I don't have a paid Teams account. I get invited to a lot of Teams meetings so I'd like to have my own background.

Comment: I believe that the images are meant to be imported through the app and not just dropped into the folder.  I can grep/search for the answer to this but I am using teams right now and can't close it down to free locked files.

Comment: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads

Answer (score 0):

None of this information is any good if you do not have a paid Teams account.
Does ANYONE have some advice for those of us who attend Teams meetings as guests but want to use our own backgrounds?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).